# How to changes values into one another in a vector smultaneously?

Tags: r, vector

I have this vector `b <- c(1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1)`

and I need to replace all 1s into 2s and all 2s into 1s.

I have tried the replace option as well as the `b==1 <- 2` but it needs to be at the same time to work.
How

Comment: Why does it need to be at the same time? Why couldn't you, for instance, change 2s to 3s, 1s to 2s then 3s to 1s? In other words, can you have an intermediate stage?

Comment: I like the lookup table approach: `map <- c("1" = 2, "2" = 1); map[b]`

Comment: Or `(!(b - 1)) + 1`, using the automatic 0 is `FALSE`, 1 is `TRUE` conversions. (Though this is pretty obtuse code, the named vector `map` approach is nice and clear.)

Comment: Just `3-b` will work if `b` is made only of `1` and `2`.

Comment: I suppose it could be separately. I might have had the wrong impression. Thank you! will give those a try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
ifelse(b==1,2,1)
```

Answer (score 6):

A bunch of different ways to do this. Not sure why you want to do it simultaneously...

But if you absolutely are obsessed with that, how about:

```
b <- ifelse(b == 1, 2, 1)
```

Or you could write a simple swap function:

```
swap <- function(x){
  if(length(us <- unique(x)) > 2L) stop("this function is too naive for this vector")
  out <- vector(class(x), length(x))
  out[x == us[1L]] <- us[2L]
  out[x == us[2L]] <- us[1L]
  out
}
```

Jota adds the lookup table approach

```
b <- c("1" = 2, "2" = 1)[b]
```

A similar version is to use `factor`s:

```
b <- factor(b, levels = c("1" = 2, "2" = 1))
```

(this looks like it didn't work, until you look at `as.integer(b)`)

That should work more generally too, e.g. `b <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3); c("1" = 3, "2" = 1, "3" = 2)[b]`, but if that seems a bit hard to wrap your head around the best way may be to just go step-by-step:

```
idx <- which(b == 1)
b[idx] <- 2
b[-idx] <- 1
```

One more way (inspired by nicola's answer below) is:

```
b <- (idx <- b == 1)*2 + !idx
```

Comment: You forgot `(b == 1) + 1` :)

Comment: @RichardScriven sure, why not! as I said, there are a _lot_ of ways to do this :)

Comment: how about `b <- (1/2)^(b-2)` while we're at it =D

Answer (score 3):

Just use simple math. If `b` is made only of 1s and 2s, just try:

```
3-b
#[1] 2 1 1 2 1 2 2 1 1 2
```

More generally, you can try:

```
(b==1)*2+(b==2)+b*(!b %in% 1:2)
```

For instance:

```
set.seed(1)
b<-sample(10)
b
#[1]  3  4  5  7  2  8  9  6 10  1
(b==1)*2+(b==2)+b*(!b %in% 1:2)
#[1]  3  4  5  7  1  8  9  6 10  2
```

Comment: i wouldn't have thought to generalize like that, but it's valid.

Comment: A variation on the same idea: `b + (b %in% 1:2)*(3-2*b)`